# what are resources you recommend to learn GPS signal processing?

Tags: spread-spectrum, books

I want to learn about GPS and other GNSS signal processing algorithms.

I have solid background in signal processing and some experience in OFDM.

Could you please recommend some books or online resource?

Comment: Well, OFDM won't help you; other than that, have you checked the resources that Wikipedia's GPS article cites? What about gnss-sdr and their references?

Comment: @MarcusMüller thanks. gnss-sdr is a very good starting point.

Answer (score 3):

A good place to start is Van Diggelen and Enge's old course, now on [YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLGvhNIiu1ubyEOJga50LJMzVXtbUq6CPo).

There's a lot of GNSS related information on Wikipedia but I would look at [Navipedia](https://gssc.esa.int/navipedia/index.php/Main_Page) first.

Finally, you could try one of open source software receivers, the most comprehensive being [gnss-sdr](https://gnss-sdr.org/).